# Does the wife in the hadith annoy her husband in the earth or jannah im still confused about the hadith

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, jannah, houri

assalamualaikum warahmatullahi wabarakatuh This hadith says : [Sunan Ibn Majah 2014](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:2014)
Im confused about the line his wife among the houris? does it take place in paradise or earth

Comment: It should be obvious that it means that the human wife annoys her on this earth and the houris are in paradise, see https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1174

Answer (score 1):

since Jannah is a place of perfect harmony it is obvious that any disharmony can only occur in this life on earth.

Comment: thank you so much